# How do I access parameters of my POST request within a controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, rest, post

Javascript:

```
$.post("/DataAPI/messageProcessor", { query: "Hello World!" }, function (data) {
  Handle(data); 
}
});
```

Controller:

```
[System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("Post")]
[System.Web.Http.ActionName("messageProcessor")]
public ResponseModel messageProcessor(string query)
{
  ResponseModel model=DoStuff(query);
  return model;
}
```

How do I access `query` from the controller. It always arrives as `query == null`. There is `Request` object available too but I am not sure how to navigate through its members to reach my `"Hellow World!"`.

Comment: try to use dataType: 'json'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to a coworker. Solution is as following:

```
public class QueryClass 
{
public string query { get; set; }
}

public ResponseModel messageProcessor(QueryClass query)
{
  ResponseModel model=DoStuff(query.query);
  return model;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't surprise me that this works, but I'm still surprised that the solutions posted by others did NOT work.

Comment: Yes. you are just passing a string to controller and it must get retrieve when you specified datatype as 'string'. If you pass some JSON object, you must need to specify datatype as 'object'. Not sure how this works. But can try this approach if i come across your issue!.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand why this work and others don't. ASP.NET MVC allows you to receive a simple string, an int, a complex type, a complex type plus simple parameters, etc. It is smart enough to map the query string or form body into any parameters or object properties from want you want to receive. I'm completely sure that a $.post('/MyController/Action1', { query : 'do stuff'}) will definitely invoke MyController.Action1(String data)

Comment: I meant MyController.Action1(String query)

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass name-value pairs from the client:

```
$.post("/DataAPI/messageProcessor"
          , { query: "Hello World!" }
          , function (data) {} );
```

Check [jQuery.Post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) for more details.

Comment: I tried that too. Still NULL. I modified the original question for your example. Still not working but thanks,

Comment: use the dataType: 'json' as param

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
$.post("/DataAPI/messageProcessor", { 'query' : 'Hello World!' }, function (data) {
     Handle(data); 
   }
});
```

Comment: that's no different from the original one I posted `$.post(...,"Hello World!", ...).

Comment: i have surrounded key & value with quots.

Comment: @AstroSharp have you checked developer tool to see what is posting to server?

Comment: Request URL:http://10.200.1.223/DataAPI/messageProcessor
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK

Form Data: <view URL encoded> Hello World!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21283/discussion-between-behnam-esmaili-and-astrosharp)