# MVC 3 JSON string not serializing into Controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3

Currently using MVC3 and using jQuery $.post function to send the ajax request to the controller action called "SearchInitiated". I'm having a little bit of a head-scratcher here because I'm not sure exactly where my issues lies. I'm sure its something minor that I have overlooked.

When I call my Controller method from an AJAX call, I am passing a json object (stringified) to a controller action. See below:

**Request Headers from Chrome**

> Accept:*/* Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded;
>   charset=UTF-8 User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64)
>   AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>
> Chrome/24.0.1312.52 Safari/537.17
>
> X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

**Form Dataview**

> connectorId:1
>
> sessionId:97e2d8b2-be9e-4138-91ed-42ef9c6a2cd6
>
> party:
>   {"Tag":null,"PartyIdentifier":"1","Address":null,"Address2":null,"BusinessName":"","CellPhoneNumber":null,"CIF":"","City":null,"Country":null,"DateOfBirth":null,"EMailAddress":null,"EmploymentTitle":null,"EmployerAddress":null,"EmployerAddress2":null,"EmployerCity":null,"EmployerName":null,"EmployerPhoneNumber":null,"EmployerState":null,"EmployerZip":null,"Fax":null,"Firstname":"TEST","Lastname":"USER","MailingAddress":null,"MailingAddress2":null,"MailingCity":null,"MailingState":null,"MailingZip":null,"Middlename":null,"PhoneNumber":null,"State":null,"TIN":"1111111","WorkPhoneNumber":null,"Zip":null}

### javascript

```
 var parties =    @(Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.SearchParties)));
      function SearchForCustomer(id)
      {

      var currentSelectedParty = GetPartyById(id)
      //SearchPost is a wrapper for $.ajax using default values for dataType and contentType
      SearchPost(URL, {
                'connectorId': '@Model.ConnectorId',
                'sessionId': '@Model.SessionId',            
                'party' :  JSON.stringify( currentSelectedParty ) 
            }
      }
```

### Controller

```
 public ActionResult SearchInitiated(int connectorId, string sessionId, SearchParty party)
 {
     code here....
 }

 public class SearchParty
    {
        public SearchParty();
        public SearchParty(string lastname, string firstname);

        public string Address
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
           public string City
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string Country
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string DateOfBirth
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        .... etc etc
}
```

However, the party object is null.

If I change the code to the following, everything deserializes correctly into the strongly typed object.

```
 public ActionResult SearchInitiated(int connectorId, string sessionId, string party)
 {
     JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            SearchParty sp =
                   json_serializer.Deserialize<SearchParty>(party);
 }
```

I know my json string is valid since it is working in the second code snippet and the value is being passed in the call. What else could I be missing?

Comment: Can you send us an example request that you are sending via post?

Comment: Why not just let the framework do the work for you? Change the signature to this: `public ActionResult SearchInitiated(int connectorId, string sessionId, SearchParty party)` and you have't to deserialize manualy. If this doesn't work, you have a problem, so post the data that you are sending to this action.

Comment: Also, I see you specified the "full" class name in the declaration but not in the deserialization. Are there any other classes called `SearchParty` in this context?

Comment: I've updated the question a little with some more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my error by modifying the javascript ajax call to this:

```
 SearchPost(URL, JSON.stringify( {
            'connectorId': '@Model.ConnectorId',
            'sessionId': '@Model.SessionId',            
            'party' :   currentSelectedParty  
        }))
```

I needed to stringify the entire data object sent in the ajax call, not just the 'party' object

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
public class SearchParty
{
  public string party { get; set; }

}

  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult SearchInitiated(SearchParty party)
   {     
       ....
       return View();

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

probably you need to set the `traditional` prop of jQuery.ajax to true in order to achieve [traditional style of param](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) serialization

put the below line of code immediatly after the document ready like

```
$(function(){
 jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;
});
```

[**This**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497093/what-is-traditional-style-of-param-serialization-in-jquery) SO question may help you further

Answer (score 1):

I would make sure you have the [Serializable] attribute on your model.  Also, make sure your request specifies party={myjson} .

Answer (score 1):

You just need to declare a class 'SearchParty' in the controller to retrieve the strongly typed object in the controller without serializing.

```
public class SearchParty  
{
 public string party { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult SearchInitiated(SearchParty party)
{
 code here....
}
```

Please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13920571/how-do-i-access-parameters-of-my-post-request-within-a-controller/) too